# LINQ ругается компилятор

Tags: c#, linq

Почему ругается компилятор на таком запросе

```
IEnumerable<string> estr = from n in s
                                   where (n.Count < 6) & n.Substring(0, 1) != "G"
                                   select n;
```

Говорит, что `оператор < не может применяться к операндам группа методов`. Почему ? Ведь Count возвращает int, а 6 это тоже int. Что не так ?

Я знаю, что можно юзать Lenght, но почему именно на Counte ругается ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы не вызываете метод `Count`.

Для решения добавьте `()`

```
IEnumerable<string> estr = from n in s
                           where (n.Count() < 6) & n.Substring(0, 1) != "G"
                           select n;
```

Кроме того, раз уж тут используются строки, то лучше использовать свойство `Length`, ему не нужны скобки

```
IEnumerable<string> estr = from n in s
                           where (n.Length < 6) & n.Substring(0, 1) != "G"
                           select n;
```

Comment: Точно. Туплю. Спасибо.

Comment: @PolyakovSergey, смотрите обновленный ответ, часто путаются свойства Count и Length - первое у списков, второе у массивов и строк